# Spurious space after command in ConTeXt

Tags: macros, spacing, context

Is it possible to define a macro in ConTeXt which gobbles space after the argument? For example, given this input:

```
\def\thing{\dosingleargument\dothing}
\def\dothing[#1]{thing#1}

\starttext

\thing[hello]
\thing[world]

\stoptext
```

This produces the following output:

[image: thinghello thingworld]

But, ideally, I'd like it to run together, like this:

[image: thinghellothingworld]

I realise I can use `\thing[hello]%`, but just wondering whether there's something easy I may have missed here. These `\thing` commands are currently being generated by a script. I could configure the script to output the `%`, but the TeX file is likely to be tweaked by hand afterwards, where it's possible the `%` may end up missing, and then the space appears again, so I'd like to try and reduce this possible human error and keep the TeX file looking tidy.

Comment: Plain TeX and LaTeX have `\ignorespaces`, so probably context has too.

Comment: It worked! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Erm, it was a guess, I don't even know how to run context, so no, I won't post an answer. Feel free to post it yourself.

Comment: Suit yourself :)

Comment: @campa As easy as `context <jobname>`

Comment: @JairoA.delRio I guessed that much but it didn't work. It's likely that I don't have a working installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this in ConTeXt, but the spurious space was removed after placing `\ignorespaces` as the end of the macro definition:

```
\def\thing{\dosingleargument\dothing}
\def\dothing[#1]{thing#1\ignorespaces}
```

Comment: `\ignorespaces` is the canonical way to do this in ConTeXt.